# Quickest way to "destroy" the contents of a drive?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, filevault

Consider a drive protected with the latest iteration of Filevault.

If I wanted to make the contents of the disk unrecoverable, I could of course do a security wipe of the entire drive - which would undoubtedly take a while.

Is there a quicker way?

Can the key material be irretrievably damaged instead for example, in such a way the encrypted contents are useless? For example dd'iing over a specific offset of the drive?

Comment: Internal or external drive? Why not just reformat with a different passphrase?

Comment: Internal disk with an APFS Container (OSX + Data) and a Bootcamp Partition. I hadn't really considered recreating the APFS container with a different PW. In practice, I guess this would have to be done from a recovery disk. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2):

The encrypted contents are already useless, unless you have the recovery key.

If someone ELSE has the recovery key, then change it.

From https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/02/02/managing-yosemites-filevault-2-with-fdesetup/

> You can add or change recovery keys using fdesetup changerecovery. To
> change to a new personal key, run the following command with root
> privileges:
>
> `fdesetup changerecovery -personal`
>
> You’ll be prompted for the password of an existing FileVault 2-enabled
> user or the existing personal recovery key. Once entered, a new
> personal recovery key will be generated and displayed. The former
> personal recovery key will no longer work.

Comment: I think this is specifically for recovery keys, where FileVault will happily run without a recovery key set at all, relying solely on the TPM + User Credentials. For example on my system:

`sudo fdesetup haspersonalrecoverykey any_user`

always returns 'false'. 

However - I'm still able to unlock the drive, and the users appear in `fdesetup list`.

Your document is exceptionally good reading though. Thank you for that!